# Using get_account_funds with betfair.py package

Tags: python, json, betfair

I am trying to use the get_account_funds method in the betfair.py package available at https://github.com/jmcarp/betfair.py. In the readme, there is example code which uses the list_event_types method and this runs perfectly for me, so my authentication is running fine. However, when I try:

```
from betfair.models import AccountFundsResponse
client.get_account_funds()
```

A bunch of errors get thrown up, ending with ApiError: UNKNOWN.Does anyone know how to overcome this error? The topline error seems to be with:

```
    121     self = args[0]
    122     if self.session_token:
--> 123         return func(*args, **kwargs)
    124     raise exceptions.NotLoggedIn()
```

Followed by:

```
    454             'getAccountFunds',
    455             utils.get_kwargs(locals()),
--> 456             model=models.AccountFundsResponse,
    457         )
```

Answer (score 0):

Betfair exchange API consist of different type of API (ex : Betting API and Account API). Each API use different endpoints.

[Betting API endpoint](https://api.developer.betfair.com/services/webapps/docs/display/1smk3cen4v3lu3yomq5qye0ni/Betting+API)

[Account API endpoint](https://api.developer.betfair.com/services/webapps/docs/display/1smk3cen4v3lu3yomq5qye0ni/Accounts+API)

getAccountFunds method can be access using Account API.

Try to change endpoint.